# Find the ratio of the area cut off a parabola $y^2=4x$ ...

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, area

Find the ratio of the area cut off a parabola $y^2=4x$ by any double ordinate to that of the corresponding rectangle contained by that double ordinate and its distance from the vertex.

I cannot interpret the second part of the question like how is the rectangle made in between the double ordinate and the vertex. I feel the ratio to be 1

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing a bit here.  I think the problem wants you to first compute the area between the parabola and the double ordinate.  Call that $A$.  Then compute the area of the rectangle which has one side the double ordinate, opposite side is a segment parallel to the double ordinate through the vertex, and the other two sides by joining the endpoints of the first two sides.  Call that $B$.  Then it wants $A/B$.

Comment: yeah, it might be the case..